# To get all ajax calls in a webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium

Is there any way in Selenium to get all Ajax call urls in a page.
Basically I need to make sure that all urls in the page and adhering to a particular protocol. I get all urls in the page usinng `<a>` and href and I can validate them.
But how do I validate those dynamic calls. Is there any way to get ajax call url?

Note : I don't have much idea about Ajax and how it works.

Comment: are you using **JQuery**?

Comment: I am using Selenium with Java. I haven't used JQuery.